# Creating Notes in LinkedNotebook

Tags: android, evernote

I am trying to create note in a shared notebook which is already shared with me. The notebook is shared with me with priveleges to modify its contents (SharedNotebookPrivilegeLevel.MODIFY_NOTEBOOK_PLUS_ACTIVITY), and I can create notes in that notebook using Evernote web client. But when I trying to create a note using SDK I received an EDAMUserException(errorCode:PERMISSION_DENIED, parameter:authenticationToken). Below is my code

```
Note note = new Note();
note.setContent(EvernoteUtil.NOTE_PREFIX + content + EvernoteUtil.NOTE_SUFFIX);
note.setTitle(title);
EvernoteSession evernoteSession = EvernoteSession.getInstance();
List<LinkedNotebook> linkedNotebooks = evernoteSession
        .getEvernoteClientFactory()
        .getNoteStoreClient()
        .listLinkedNotebooks();
LinkedNotebook current = null;
for (LinkedNotebook linkedNotebook : linkedNotebooks) {
    if (linkedNotebook.getShareName().equals(notebookName)) {
        current = linkedNotebook;
    }
}
if (current == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException();
THttpClient tHttpClient = new THttpClient(current.getNoteStoreUrl());
TBinaryProtocol tBinaryProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(tHttpClient);
NoteStore.Client client = new NoteStore.Client(tBinaryProtocol, tBinaryProtocol);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = client.authenticateToSharedNotebook(current.getShareKey(),
        evernoteSession.getAuthToken());
String shareToken = authenticationResult.getAuthenticationToken();
SharedNotebook sharedNotebook = client.getSharedNotebookByAuth(shareToken);
String sharedNotebookGuid = sharedNotebook.getNotebookGuid();
note.setGuid(sharedNotebookGuid);
Note createdNote = client.createNote(shareToken, note);
return createdNote;
```

I've used [this](http://laurent.sarrazin.io/2014/05/evernote-api-create-notes-in-a-linked-notebook.html) article to create notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One mistake I found is that

```
note.setGuid(sharedNotebookGuid);
```

has to be

```
note.setNotebookGuid(sharedNotebookGuid);
```